# Fix two divs to the bottom and top of another div

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to fix two divs to the bottom and top of another div.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/NathaliaZeed/hm9c6ta6/2/)

```
<div id="subG">
    <div id="subUp"> TTTTT </div> //This to be fixed on top of this parent div
    <div id="subGH"> 
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div id="subDwn"> BBBB </div> //This to be fixed at the bottom of this parent div
</div>
```

css:

```
#subG{
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#subGH{
    height: 99%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: -15px;
}
#subUp #subDwn{
    position: relative;
}
```

So the final would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you need like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hm9c6ta6/4/ ?

Comment: @Amit:  thanks for your comment. No. I need to have the scrolling as well...

Comment: where do you need scrolling, you didnt showed that in your expected output image?

Comment: wt about this https://jsfiddle.net/hm9c6ta6/9/?

Comment: @Beki, which two div's you need to place, can you please explain clearly.

Comment: @stanze: `subUp` to be fixed to the top of `subGH` and `subDwn` to be fixed to the bottom of `subGH`

Comment: @Beki, can you please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this demo, which you are looking for.
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/hm9c6ta6/13/)

```
#subUp{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#subDwn{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hm9c6ta6/11/)**

Try to use `class` instead of `ID`'s where ever you can reuse the same style within a page

CSS:

```
.subG {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width:150px;
}
.subUp, .subDwn {
    height: 20px;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.subGH {
    display:block;
    background-color:yellow;
    height: 60px;
     overflow: auto;
       right: -15px;    
    position: relative;
}
.subGH img {
    width:100%;  
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="subG">
    <div class="subUp">TTTTT</div>
    <div class="subGH">
        <img src="http://pngimg.com/upload/small/kettle_PNG8730.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="subDwn">BBBB</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. why use `.subUp, .subDwn` when it's possible to use one for both?

Comment: yes you can, if you need different color options,i gave separately.. If you have same style for both, use single class..

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```css
#subG {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
#subGH {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 99%;
    left: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    right: 5px;
    top: 0;
}
#subUp, #subDwn {
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
#subDwn {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
use mouse wheel over this image
<div id="subG">
    <div id="subUp"> TTTTT </div> 
    <div id="subGH"> 
        <img src="http://img42.com/lwZZW+">
    </div>
    <div id="subDwn"> BBBB </div> 
</div>
```

Hope it helps.